# C Strange behaviour on 64-bit server

Tags: c, apache, module, gdb

I have this strange behaviour in Apache post_config handler :

```
int setup_module(apr_pool_t *p, apr_pool_t *plog, apr_pool_t *ptemp,server_rec *s)
{
    //1
    my_config_t *config =  ap_get_module_config(s->module_config, &my_module);

    //2
    log_me(config->logfp, apr_psprintf(ptemp, "My module version %s\n", MY_VERSION));

    //3
    log_me(config->logfp, "Starting the batch job");

    return OK;
}
```

log_me is a custom function declared in another file and declared in the header (it is resolved at compile time).

In the step2 I can see that config has a valid value, however step 3 fails with a SEGSEGV and if I try to debug it I can see this :

//step 2
gdb: print config
$1 = (my_config_t *)0x7a8098

//step 3
gdb: print config
Cannot access memory at address 0x38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found teh problem.

In log_me I was making :

int nbytes = strlen(message);

instead of:

apr_size_t nbytes = strlen(message);

Being on 64 bits this screwed all.. no idea why yet.

Comment: It doesn't seem likely that was the real problem.  It is more likely that it shifted stack or memory usage around and hid the problem.

Comment: Actually if i commented this handler i had no issues.
Also this module worked perfectly on Solaris 10 with default 32 bit (gcc, apache and LD library path). Here I have all on 64

Comment: Maybe you're not including `string.h` in the file containing `log_me`?

Answer (score 1):

Something is overwriting the config pointer.  Can you put a breakpoint on the memory location and see what is executing the overwrite?  Here's a guide to how to do this:
http://www.technochakra.com/debugging-types-of-data-breakpoints-in-gdb/

Answer (score 1):

What is `ptemp` passed into setup_module, and is it safe to use it as a buffer for your sprintf?  Is it possible `ptemp` points to a memory area that isn't large enough to hold that string?

Maybe you should declare an auto variable (`char buffer[80];`) and use that for your sprintf?

Comment: ptemp is a temporary memory pool cleared after the config phase. apr_psprintf is a function providd by apr (Apache portable runtime) and should not have buffer issues like you are mentioning